# PL/SQL Report- how to find only the highest value

Tags: oracle

Im trying to write a report showing active students and their highest tuition they paid. I want only the highest tuition to be shown, what is wrong with this statement:

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, f.total_price
FROM finance f
LEFT JOIN student c on (s.student_id=f.student_id) 
WHERE s.active=1
GROUP BY s.student_id
HAVING f.total_price=MAX(f.total_price);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to show us your table structure. We can assume but it may not be correct.

Comment: What is wrong? A lot of things. To begin with, you give table `student` the alias `c` but then you reference it as `s`. Then, you use a non-`GROUP BY` column, `total_price`, in the `HAVING` clause. You have even more non-`GROUP BY` columns in `SELECT` (the first and the last name).

Comment: @mathguy I am just learning, thank you for your help! could you suggest how i can improve this code to get the result i need?

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar lets say in student there is only id name and last name, but in finance there is student id, tuition, date. I want to show only rows with max tuition paid by student.